# Access current item of ng-repeat loop outside of it and pass its property to outside function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have ng-repeat loop which loops collection of image items in bootstrap carousel, and each image item has id, title and imagename property. Outside ng-repeat loop I have remove button with ng-click function that accepts imageid to delete it. But, as this button is outside loop, it doesn't have access to current image in loop.

```
<div ng-repeat="img in images" ng-class="{'active':$first}">
     <img ng-src="folder/{{img.imagename}}">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
           <p>{{img.id}}</p>
           <p>{{image.title}}</p>
       </div>
</div>

<div ng-click="remove(img.id)">
   <i class="fa fa-times fa-1x"></i>
</div>
```

If I put remove button inside loop it works, but is it possible to keep track of current image from loop and have only one remove button outside loop, to which I can pass id of current image (image displayed on carousel).

Comment: No, you need to let your carousel track the current displayed image. You can not use the one from `ng-repeat`, this is just for building the DOM.

Comment: "current image (image displayed on carousel)" 

ng-repeat loop over images collection to create bootstrap carousel. There is remove button on carousel container (outside this loop) that needs to be aware of current image displayed on carousel. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yea I re-read the question and got that. It is not possible, `ng-repeat` doesn't know which one is the one displayed.

Comment: How can I make my carousel to track current displayed image and for example, to store it in $scope.selectedImage so I can use it wherever in controller's scope?
Maybe something with watchers on slide events? P.S Is it possible to do that avoiding jQuery?

Comment: The carousel implementation you are using should have a notion of the current image displayed. Which one are you using?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 carousel:

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" ></div>

Comment: See potential answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some bindings like this one: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel - it has the active image accessible.

This is not tested, you need to adapt it to your code.

```
<div uib-carousel active="active">
  <div uib-slide ng-repeat="img in images track by img.imagename" index="img.imagename">
    <img ng-src="folder/{{img.imagename}}">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
       <p>{{img.id}}</p>
       <p>{{image.title}}</p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div ng-click="remove(active)">
   <i class="fa fa-times fa-1x"></i>
</div>
```